# Is there a way to block self-following in Follow model?

Tags: python, django

My model structure looks like this:

```py
from django.db import models


class Follow(models.Model):
    follower = models.ForeignKey('accounts.User', related_name='following',
                                 on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    user = models.ForeignKey('accounts.User', related_name='followers',
                             on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    class Meta:
        unique_together = (('user', 'follower',),)

    def __str__(self):
        return f'{self.follower.username} follows {self.user.username}'
```

I'm looking for something similar to "unique_together" but for the same user.
I know there're possibilities to block it in API but I want it to do it from model level.

Answer (score 1):

You can either:

- as the other answer says, override `clean()` or `save()` to ensure `follower != user`,
- or if you're using a supported database, you could [add a Check constraint](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/constraints/#checkconstraint) to do the same on the database level.

Comment: Thanks for the Check constraint tip :D

Answer (score 0):

Overriding the `save` method can do the trick here. In your model save method you can check and raise an exception if both follower and user are same. I don't think you would be able to do it using any constraint as unique_together.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the answers but I did it this way.

```py
from django.dispatch import receiver
from django.db import models
from django.db.models.signals import pre_save
from django.core.exceptions import ValidationError


class Follow(models.Model):
    follower = models.ForeignKey('accounts.User', related_name='following',
                                 on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    user = models.ForeignKey('accounts.User', related_name='followers',
                             on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    class Meta:
        unique_together = (('user', 'follower',),)

    def __str__(self):
        return f'{self.follower.username} follows {self.user.username}'


@receiver(pre_save, sender=Follow)
def check_self_following(sender, instance, **kwargs):
    if instance.follower == instance.user:
        raise ValidationError('You can not follow yourself')
```